# Prove periodicity of a function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f : \Bbb{R} \to [1, 2]$ and $$f(x + p) = 1 + \sqrt{2f(x) - \{f(x)\}^2}$$

For some $p \in \Bbb R$. and $\{\cdot\}$ is fractional part function Prove that $f$ is a periodic function.

I think the question is not true, here is my attempt at it.

If $f(x) = 2$ for some $x \in \Bbb R$ then,

$$f(x + p) = 1 + \sqrt{4} = 3$$ Thus $f(x) \ne 2$

which means $\lfloor f(x) \rfloor = 1$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Simplify the square root I get, $$f(x + p) = 1 + \sqrt{4f(x) - 1 - f^2(x)}$$

Since the range is between $1$ and $2$,

$$ 1 \le 1 + \sqrt{4f(x) - 1 - f^2(x)} \le 2$$

$$ 0 \le \sqrt{4f(x) - 1 - f^2(x)} \le 1$$

Since $\sqrt{x} \in [0,1] \iff x \in [0,1]$

So,

$$ 0 \le 4f(x) - 1 - f^2(x) \le 1$$

So, $f(x) \in [2 + \sqrt{3}, 3 + \sqrt{3} ]$, since $\require{cancel}[2 + \sqrt{3}, 3 + \sqrt{3} ] \cancel{\subseteq} [1, 2]$,

Thus there is no $x \in \Bbb R$ for which $f(x)$ satisfy the given condition and hence the proposition is not true.

Am I correct ?

Comment: I think this question makes sense if it is $f(x+p) = 1+\sqrt {2f(x) + f^2(x)}$  but not if it is $f(x+p) = 1+\sqrt {2f(x) + \{f(x)\}^2}$ as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final step is wrong. $0 \leq 4y-1-y^2 \leq 1$ implies $2-\sqrt{3} \leq y \leq 2-\sqrt{2}$ or $2+\sqrt{3} \leq y \leq 2+\sqrt{2}$. The former interval lies in $[0,1]$. The quadratic curves both down *and* up ;)

Comment: I forgot the negative root. God. I am sorry for my silly mistake.

Comment: @123 Happens to us all.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$[f(x+p)-1]^2=2f(x)-f^2(x)=1-[f(x)-1]^2$$

and then make $x:=x+p$ and get

$$[f(x+2p)-1]^2=1-[f(x+p)-1]^2=[f(x)-1]^2$$

so,

$$|f(x+2p)-1|=|f(x)-1|\quad (1)$$

Once, $f(x)\ge 1$ then from $(1)$ we get

$$f(x+2p)=f(x)$$

what sugest us that $f$ is periodic and the period is $2p$.

Comment: How did you get $$[f(x+p)-1]^2=2f(x)-f^2(x)$$ ? I am unable to think this step. sorry.

Comment: @Hushus46 But that should give $$[f(x+p)-1]^2=4f(x)-f^2(x) - 1$$ ?

Comment: @Hushus46 I think $\{x\}$ is a fractional part function. That means it is $x - \lfloor x \rfloor$. So $\{x\}^2 = (x - \lfloor x \rfloor)^2$ not $x^2$.

Comment: @A---B oh my mistake, sorry for the confusion. I will remove my comment accordingly

Comment: @123: Updated. Is it clear now?

Comment: @Arnaldo Tell me if I am wrong but your initial step is wrong, it should be $$(f(x+p)- 1)^2 = 4f(x) - f^2(x) \color{red}{- 1}$$.

Comment: @123: Oh sorry. I just realized what $\{\}$ means. I have to check the calculations again.